# Node.js runserver on GCP Virtual Machine

Tags: python, node.js, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, httpserver

I have a python application hosted by a node.js frontend. I am running that on a linux vm on Google Cloud virtual machine (GCP).
 `node appname runserver 8080` command starts local server within VM but I am wondering what would be step by step process to access it via a DNS from outside world.

Or if there is better approach to host python ML applications behind a web interface, then please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `forever`  for this.

Forever will move the node process to the background and service will keep running in the background even if you log out of the server. And In order to access from outside point a DNS domain to this IP address of the machine and then Proxy Pass the request on port 80 to the port your service is running on.

Then you will be able to access it via domain name.

Look for ProxyPass directive in the Http server. That would work for you. :D

Comment: instead of forever I can use tmux also I think.. My main problem is DNS (Accessing localhost application outside the VM)

Comment: You need webserver for this either Apache or nginx if you are planning for Apache go through this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04 don't forget to add server name as your domain name in Apache configuration